# Javascript variable export to python

Tags: javascript, python

Quick question. Can i somehow access javascript variable inside script and then use it to make python graphs?

i got javascript script running on my website, i need to "export" variables inside script after leaving website, then use it in python script running somewhere else. My site is basic html page collecting data about its usage.

```
window.onload = function(){
    var heatmapInstance = h337.create({
      container: document.querySelector('.heatmap'),
      radius: 90
    });

    document.querySelector('.heatmap').onmousemove = function(ev) {
      heatmapInstance.addData({
        x: ev.layerX,
        y: ev.layerY,
        value: 1
      });
    };
  }


  function getHeatMap() {
    var currentData = heatmapInstance.getData();
    return currentData;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [beacon API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Beacon_API) to flush data when users close the tab, in supported browsers, to your back-end.

```
window.onload = window.onunload = function analytics(event) {
  if (!navigator.sendBeacon) return;

  var url = "https://example.com/analytics";
  // Create the data to send
  var data = "state=" + event.type + "&location=" + location.href;

  // Send the beacon
  var status = navigator.sendBeacon(url, data);

  // Log the data and result
  console.log("sendBeacon: URL = ", url, "; data = ", data, "; status = ", status);
};
```